# Automatically insert text in headings wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would have to automatically insert something like "Advertising" before every heading in WordPress. However, I would have to edit over 100 posts afterwards. Do you have an idea how I could automate this?

So far I don't have an idea for it.

Comment: Get all the posts using `get_posts`. (Set `posts_per_page` to -1.)

Comment: Then loop through the posts and `get_the_title()`. Add « advertising » before the title and call `wp_update_post` for this post ID with the new title.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.